# Ruby On Rails Dynamic Where Search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, search

I am using postgres for the db.

Service Address Controller contains this line

`@service_addresses = ServiceAddress.where("customer_id =?" , params[:customer_id]).search(params[:search])`

Service Address Model Method:

`def self.search(query)
    where("street LIKE ? OR city LIKE ?", "%#{query.to_s}%","%{query.to_s}%")
end`

In my view I have a search bar that sends params

`service_addresses?utf8=✓&search=123+Echo+Dr+New+York`

Lets assume I have two columns on my view `Street` & `City`

If I search `123 Echo Dr. New York` it will NOT return a record where `Street = 123 Echo Dr. and the City = New York`

However, if I simply search `123 Echo Dr.` or `123` it will return all records that have that in the `Street` or `City` column. Similairly if I search `New York` it will return records that contain `New York`

I tried parsing out the search param into an array (successfully) and then using a loop to essentially build a string of `"%#{parsed_query[i]}%"` However when I tried to pass the string of binds to my `where` statement, but I got an error stating I have the wrong number of binds. It was treating my string variable as one bind.

Not able to use Data Tables gem!

Thank you SOF community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the tokens parsed from the query string to build up your query with ActiveRecord. Note that this will result in a SQL query many AND conditions.

```
@service_addresses = ServiceAddress.where("customer_id =?" , params[:customer_id])
parsed_query.each do |token|
  @service_addresses = @service_addresses.search(token)
end
```

#### Update for case-insensitivity

To ignore case you can convert all strings to either uppercase or lowercase.

```
# Service Address Model Method: 
def self.search(query)
    where("upper(street) LIKE ? OR upper(city) LIKE ?", "%#{query.to_s.upcase}%","%{query.to_s.upcase}%")
end
```

#### Alternative

You may wish to look into document matching (full-text search). Postgres has some nice support for this. The topic is too much to cover here, but there are many resources online. A good place to start is the [Postgres documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/textsearch-intro.html)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Wizard of Ogz. Your solution worked for the most part, but how would I make it not case sensitive. If I enter `New york` it will not find records with `New York`

Comment: See the update in my answer about the case sensitivity.

Comment: Lifesaver, thanks a bunch! I felt like I was overlooking something while trying to build a massive string of binds....

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you problem, try this:

```
def self.search(keyword)
  keyword_search = "%#{keyword.downcase}%"
  where('lower(city) LIKE :search OR lower(street) LIKE :search', search: keyword_search)
end
```